# Checking for duplicate values in MongoDB database with php

Tags: php, mongodb

I need to do a task where I add "people" to a mongoDB database. One of their values is an ID value, I need to ensure that there is never a duplicate ID value in the DB, How can I go about checking the DB if the ID value is the same as what I am trying to insert before inserting a new "person" into the collection.

Comment: You shouldn't. Use a [unique index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/) instead.